# Multilingual Drop down reverting to default selection

Tags: asp.net-core

OK So I now have languages working and it's selecting the appropriate language for that picked in the dropdown. However, the dropdown is not remembering the selected language the cookie is being written ok but the dropdown goes back to the default. 
I find the official Microsoft docs to be very lacking in this detail I am using the admin lte theme.

SelectLanguage.Html

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.NativeName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="languageDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        @Localizer["Language"]
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown">
        @foreach (var language in @cultureItems)
        {
            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-culture="@language.Value" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">@language.Text</a>
        }
    </div>
</li>
```

Set Language Function

```
 public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)  {
   Response.Cookies.Append(
   CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
   CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
   new CookieOptions {Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1)}
 );

 return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
 }
```

In My Home Controller I set the following.

```
 public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)   
 {
     _logger = logger;
     _localizer = localizer;           

   }
```

This is my startup class

```
namespace RoundTableMVCore31
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("fr") };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
                };
            });


            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var supportedCultures = new string[] { "en-GB", "fr-FR" };

            app.UseRequestLocalization();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{culture=en-gb}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();


            });


        }
    }
}
```

Also, how does one include the country flags is there a standard way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

> the dropdown is not remembering the selected language the cookie is being written ok but the dropdown goes back to the default.

If you'd like to keep '**Active**' state of selected item of the dropdown after you changed selected language, to achieve it, you can dynamically specify `.active` CSS class to selected item based on the value of cookie [`.AspNetCore.Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cookierequestcultureprovider), like below.

*In _Layout.cshtml file*

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var cl = getCookie(".AspNetCore.Culture");
        if (cl != "") {
            var c = cl.split('|')[0].substring(2);
            //console.log(c);

            $("#lan-items a.active").removeClass("active");

            //your code logic here

            switch (c) {
                case "fr":
                    var atag = $("#lan-items a.dropdown-item")[1];

                    $(atag).addClass("active");
                    break;

                case "en":
                    var atag = $("#lan-items a.dropdown-item")[0];

                    $(atag).addClass("active");
                    break;
            }
        }
    })

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

*Specify dropdown-menu div with id "lan-items"*

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="lan-items" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown">
    @foreach (var language in @cultureItems)
    {
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-culture="@language.Value" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">@language.Text</a>
    }
</div>
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: Thanks that step is left out of the ms documentation and believe it should be added.

Comment: Just curious how would one add the lanugage flag in is that possible